# Bean validation for Springboot request param

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a use case wherein we are having multiple parameters being passed in the REST controller, and the parameters have to be validated for not empty, and some custom validations. Also, for some of the parameters the filter options are supported with startswith, endswith. I am able to validate parameters for first filter level, but could not make it work for next filter level. For example: the query string is filter.firstname and it is supported with optional of startswith and endswith.
Can someone help by providing some suggestions on how can I validate the parameter when someone is passing filter.firstname or filter.firstname.startswith for non-empty values?

This is the sample code for Controller.

````java
 @GetMapping()
    public CustomerResponseData findCustomers(@Valid FilterCustomer filter, HttpServletRequest request)


public class FilterCustomer {

    @Valid
    private FilterCustomerCriteria filter;

}


public class FilterCustomerCriteria {

    @NotBlank
    private String firstname;

    @NotBlank
    private String lastname;
}


public class FilterCustomerFinerCriteria {

    @NotBlank
    private String startswith;

    @NotBlank
    private String endswith;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you say that the validation framework doesn't have annotations for your custom validation logic on some fields (`@NotBlank` is not enough).

In this case, you can always create your own custom validators that will implement the validation logic.

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/create-your-own-constraint-with-bean-validation-20) is a link to example of how to do this,
but to recap:

- You have to implement a class that implements `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` and add validation logic in its `public boolean isValid` method
- Then create a custom annotation (like `@NotBlank but your own one) and set among other things a meta-annotation`@Constraint(validatedBy = { YourValidator.class })`

Then use this annotation just like any other validation annotation

Comment: Actually I am looking to get the validations on the second level of request param, I am able to validate filter.firstname if it is not present, but then I want to do the similar validation when someone passes filter.firstname.startswith, and then filter.firstname is not required.